# Convert Point Geometry to list

Tags: python, geometry, tuples, gdal, ogr

I have the following script that creates a point geometry. How can I convert this point geometry to a list only containing the coordiantes to look like `[258432.79138201929, 1001957.4394514663]`?

```
>>> import ogr
>>> driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
>>> pointshp = driver.Open('U:/My Documents/Tool/shp/point.shp', 0)

>>> pointlyr = pointshp.GetLayer()

>>> point_geom = point.GetGeometryRef()

>>> print point_geom

POINT (258432.79138201929 1001957.4394514663)
```

Comment: what is `point`? as in `point.GetGeometryRef()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a point object has xyz coordinates.

```
[point_geom.x, point_geom.y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming point_geom is literally `"POINT (258432.79138201929 1001957.4394514663)"` (ie a string)

You can do:

```
map(float,point_geom[7:-1].split(' '))
```

`point_geom[7:-1]` gives `"258432.79138201929 1001957.4394514663"`
`point_geom[7:-1].split(' ')` gives `['258432.79138201929', '1001957.4394514663']`
`map(float,point_geom[7:-1].split(' '))` coerces the strings to floats

Comment: Probably isn't just a string; `print` is not the same as `repr`.